# Recursive Website Tree in Python

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a program in Python using BeautifulSoup4 that starts at a random Wikipedia article, and grabs the first two links within the paragraph section only. I would like to create a tree, where it gets the first two links of the random article, then it goes to those two links and grabs the first two links on those pages, and so on. Naturally, it makes sense to use recursion, but I am stuck.

Here is my code in abstraction:

```
def tree(link):
    branch = get_links(link) # Function returns the first two links on the article in a list of strings
    return tree(branch[0]), tree(branch[1])

origin = get_random_article() # Returns a link to a random Wikipedia article as a string

links = tree(origin)
```

This code creates an infinite loop, obviously i need some sort of iterative process, or loop, to limit it.

Here is what I am stuck on:

1. I need some sort of limiter as to how many branches it creates, so it doesn't loop indefinitely
2. A way to return all the links it finds once its created the specified amount of branches

I'll output the data for a file or something, but right now, any help on how to create this tree is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Lucas

Comment: You can keep a global counter or pass in an additional argument to the method of the limit

Comment: Not sure why you're using beautifulsoup alone to do this. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a queue or a stack. Start at a random article get the two links, add them to the queue. get one link from the queue, and repeat. Whenever you get an article from the queue, increment the count. If the count is greater than the limit you want, stop.

Nonetheless, as mentioned by @cricket_007 try scrapy

Comment: Thank you. This helped me figure it out.